# Remove unnecessary recomposition

Tags: scroll, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have Scaffold with Column of fields and AndroidView with big text field.

Then I write in AndroidView something - MainFields recomposing all times.

I think its because of scaffoldPadding and scrollState.

But I need to make both MainFields and AndroidView with scroll.

How can I make scroll with no recomposition of MainFields?

```
Scaffold(){ scaffoldPadding ->
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
 Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(scaffoldPadding).verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
  MainFields(viewModel = viewModel){
  //MainFields - some Column with fields which I want to make not recomposable
  }
  AndroidView(viewModel = viewModel) //webview
 }
}
```